# CNN-LSTM or LSTM better for univariate Time series forecasting?

Tags: forecasting, conv-neural-network, lstm, univariate

I am working with simulated univariate sequential data and the goal is to forecast that data. I was wondering which model CNN-LSTM or LSTM is better for predicting univariate time series data. Both models are used for time series forecasting, but I can't find information about how well CNN-LSTM actually is for forecasting univariate data. I mainly find information about multivariate forecasting, for example in this [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-62463-7_40).

LSTM models are for sure options to model univariate time series like they mention in this [post](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiY_t_Wy6f4AhWKhP0HHYzlBscQFnoECAMQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmachinelearningmastery.com%2Fhow-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting%2F&usg=AOvVaw3_LCB4EqwNSPHGEYUvIzug):

> LSTMs can be used to model univariate time series forecasting
> problems. These are problems comprised of a single series of
> observations and a model is required to learn from the series of past
> observations to predict the next value in the sequence.

Also, like in this [post](https://analyticsindiamag.com/tutorial-on-univariate-single-step-style-lstm-in-time-series-forecasting/) they mention that LSTM is a good option for univariate data analysis because of the feedback connections:

> Unlike any feedforward neural network, LSTM has feedback connections.
> Therefore, it can predict values for point data and can predict
> sequential data like weather, stock market data, or work with audio or
> video data, which is considered sequential data.

In this post ([Is it a good idea to use CNN to classify 1D signal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403502/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-cnn-to-classify-1d-signal)) they mention that CNN is a possible approach for 1D signals:

> I guess that by 1D signal you mean time-series data, where you assume
> temporal dependence between the values. In such cases convolutional
> neural networks (CNN) are one of the possible approaches.

But I was wondering, is CNN-LSTM or just LSTM better for forecasting univariate time series data, or are they both good options?

Comment: Both could be good options. There is always a tradeoff between given characteristics of dataset and the choice of architecture. One advantage of CNNs are they will enhance so called representation learning compare to so called vanilla LSTM.